# Remove this 'crackle' from song with Audacity?

Tags: audio, audacity, digital-audio

I purchased a song from AudioJungle and unfortunately it has some type of crackle artifact that I can't seem to remove. Here's a brief clip of the audio:
http://puu.sh/1WAC6/12bf9a35f5.mp3

You can hear what almost sounds like a vibration on the right channel. I really don't know of a better way to describe it or what the proper term for this is (which makes it difficult to search for). Is there a way to remove this with Audacity or a similar program?

Comment: You paid for royalty-free audio, so no way to complain about the crackling?

Comment: @Karan Author has been inactive for a while.